# Excel VBA Loop Through Named Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I am trying to loop through a named range in Excel and set its value equal to another named range that is dynamic in value (called `SensitivityResults`).  How do I get Excel to essentially say:

```
Range("Scenario1").Value = Range("SensitivityResults").Value

Range("Scenario2").Value = Range("SensitivityResults").Value

Range("Scenario2").Value = Range("SensitivityResults").Value
```

etc...

My code as follows does not work:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim s As Integer

For i = 1 To 20
  For s = 1 To 20 
    Range("Active_Scenaro") = s
    Calculate
    Range("Scenario(i)").Value = Range("SensitivityResults").Value
  Next s
Next i
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to append the counter `i` as string to your fixed name `Scenario`:

```
Range("Scenario" & i).Value = Range("SensitivityResults").Value
```

Comment: very useful thanks. How do I get both loop values, s and i to update at the same time rather than having it run through all the s's and then updating the i's after?

Comment: @Reno not exactly sure about what you mean, but: Try to use only one loop (like `i` loop only and use `Range("Active_Scenaro") = i`? If this is not what you want please edit your original question, be more specific and give an example.